# Monero GUI: How do I switch back to my Ledger Nano S wallet from my original wallet

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, ledger

I have just created a new wallet using my Ledger Nano S, all went fine.

I then closed the new wallet in order to open my original wallet so I could transfer the funds over to my new wallet. Again, fine.

I now though, cannot seem to work out how to switch back to my new ledger wallet.

On opening the Monero GUI I am asked to provide my password for my old Wallet. If I click cancel, and choose "open a wallet from file" I am only shown the .keys file of my old wallet.

Where can I find the .keys for my new Ledger wallet?

Answer (score 1):

Wow, I'm dumb.

If anyone else out there is having this problem (Switching between Monero Wallets)

Want to unlock a different Wallet? Follow these steps:

1. Open Monero GUI
2. Click cancel instead of entering password.
3. Choose Language
4. Click "Open a wallet from file"
5. File Explorer window opens (Windows)
6. Choose the Destination where keys are saved (Default: This PC> Documents>
   Monero> Wallets)
7. Open desired Wallet folder
8. Select .keys file
9. Press Open
10. Enter Password